# rename _id field in find()

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I use the file_name as the _id in the collection.
But I don't want to query _id and change it to file_name everytime.Is there any method to rename name in python?
The method I know is

```
data = mongo.collection.find()
for row in data:
    row['file_name'] = row.pop('_id')
```

or

```
mongo.collection.aggregate({},{'$project':...})
```

Which one is better. Or any better method.

Comment: The projection is a better technique, as the change happens on the server. If you are using MongoDB v4.4+, you can change a field name in the projection of a `find` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this in the [db.collection.find](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.4/reference/method/db.collection.find/#use-aggregation-expression)

from mongodb4.4+

use `mongo.collection.find({},{'filename':'$_id','_id':0})`